# Outlook 2013 HTML newsletter header not correct

Tags: html, image, outlook-2013

We seem to be having some problem with displaying our newsletter in some Outlook 2013's. This newsletter was a template created by a third party. But when we upload it to an email and send it, it works perfectly in almost all cases.(gmail, hotmail, webmail,...) and even in most outlook versions except in a few 2013 Outlook's but not all. The problem is that an image is justed as header in the newsletter and in some case this doesn't fill the whole are as you can see below. In the second image you can see that there is whitespace on the side of the image that shouldn't be there.

Can anyone tell me how i can fix this? Thnx

[image]
[image]

Here you can find the code used to display the image on the HTML template:

```
<body style="margin: 0; background: #e5f1fc;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; background: #eff7fc;"><tr><td style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background: #e5f1fc;">

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="width: 100%; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                    <a href="http://www.ourdomain.be"><img alt="Companyname" src="images/header.jpg" style="margin: 0; border: 0; display: inline-block;"  /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr><td colspan="5" style="width: 800px; height: 30px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td></tr>             
            <tr>
```

EDIT:The problem only seems to appear on our new Dell Lattitude 5540 laptops. Every other 2013 installation shows the email perfectly. Only the laptops have this problem. I can't understand what the problem can be. Does anyone have an idea?

Thnx

Comment: The `width: 800px` looks strange here. What if the window is wider?

Comment: what would you put then? 100%

Comment: I would replace 800px with 100% and set `width: 100%` even to the `img` element. But I’ve never worked with HTML email messages, just with web. I don’t know the idiosyncrasies of email clients.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the rest of the code, but I'd bet there is something in the email, below the header, that is wider than `800px`. In my experience with HTML emails and Outlook, it's either that or an issue with Outlook misunderstanding `colspan`. Here's an answer from a previous, similar question:

> Outlook has an issue where if you put a colspan in the first row of a table, it will mess up the widths of the subsequent rows. The work around for this is that you need to specify your cell widths in the top row, even if it is an empty row.

You may need to specify the `width` in your first `<table>` to fix it.

Comment: In the first table there is a width at 100% but even if i change that the problem is nog resolved.

Comment: Percentages are ignored in the `width` attribute; you'll need to use a fixed value.